# Use other images for different resolutions

Tags: html, image, slider, resolution

I'm making a website, but I've a problem. I've made a slider over the whole width of the screen, but I want to use smaller images for a small resolution, and bigger images for a big resolution. The images from my slider are written in html. Is this possible, and how can I do this?

This is my website: http://www.yannickluijten.be

Comment: what have you looked at so far? Its perfectly possible but it would be nice to see what you have tried before we all give you the answer.

Comment: I've found something with different stylesheets but that's not what I want. I've actually no idea how I have to do it.

Comment: my images from my slider are written in html (img) and f.e. people with a 27inch screen needs an image with a 2560 width or something like that and those images are very large so people with a smaller resolution has to load the image very long. So I want to load a different image for people with a large/small resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate CSS media queries. They allow you to set specific styles (or import who different stylesheets) based on the properties of the browser (including window size).

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: This answer isn't very helpful though since he specifies that his images are "hardcoded" as `img` tags. In the comments he also says he doesn't want a multi-stylesheet solution.

Comment: @Codemonkey while I agree this is what he states, I don't really think the OP knows what he wants.  He asks a question and states he has no clue, then when a perfectly valid solution is given he states its not what he wants but doesn't provide any information on what he does want.

Comment: I just don't know how I have to do it, but different stylesheets is not the way I'm going to do it.

Comment: @user1211376 You don't need different stylesheet, you can just set background-image styles within the same stylesheet, but use different images and different image sizes for it based on the user's browser window width for example.

Comment: @user1211376 this is not a multi stylesheet solution, however even if it were, if you are so determined to turn down peoples answers without having any of your own then why bother asking the question?

Answer (score 0):

From your latest comment I would suggest the following solution.

Either use media queries like the other answer (although this is only supported by CSS3) or:

I would probably use javascript.  Detect the users screen resolution then insert the src into the image tags dependant on the screen resolution.  You could keep a map of resolution range to img srcs.

Comment: Do you maybe have an example of what you said? I don't have experience with javascript.

Comment: I suggest going at looking at javascript, search for javascript screen resolution, javascript find element by id and javascript set attribute.  This will give you all the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to do away with the silly `img` tags and instead use `div`s with background images. But if you're adamant about using `img` tags I suppose you could save your images like this:

```
./
|-- some_image_1024x500.png
|-- some_image_512x250.png
|-- another_image_1024x500.png
|-- another_image_512x250.png
|-- third_image_1024x500.png
|-- third_image_512x250.png
|-- ...
```

Then add a special class for image tags that should change image resolution based on window size, for instance `<img class="width-sensitive" src="images/some_image_1024x500.png" />`

Then write a JavaScript function to check the window size and perform the image source replacements, for instance (pseudocode with jQuery):

```
// This function is terribly unDRY and ugly but it's just an example
function process_image_sizes() {
    var images = $('img.width-sensitive');

    if($(window).width() > 800) {
        images.each(function(index, element) {
            var src = $(element).prop('src');
            if(/512x250\.png$/.test(src)) {
                $(element).prop('src', src.replace('512x250', '1024x500'));
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        images.each(function(index, element) {
            var src = $(element).prop('src');
            if(/1024x500\.png$/.test(src)) {
                $(element).prop('src', src.replace('1024x512', '512x250'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then run that function once on page load:

```
$(function() { process_image_sizes(); });
```

And whenever the window resizes:

```
$(window).on('resize', process_image_sizes);
```

I hope that was of some help.

---

EDIT: Just as an afterthought, you probably want to start with the small images by default then switch to the larger images on resize. I still recommend just using CSS though.

Comment: @JonTaylor: I think it's silly to use `img` tags for site designs. That stuff should be in style sheets! :-)

Comment: Uhh what? are you saying you should not use `img` tags? If so what is the point in an `img` tag?  I don't think that the image itself should be the stylesheets responsibility, I think the look of the image, size etc displayed on screen is the responsibility of the stylesheet.

Comment: @JonTaylor: I think `img` tags should be used for images that are part of the site **content**, not the site **design**. I think it looks unprofessional when images that should glide into the background of a design are selectable and draggable etc.

Comment: I agree with your comment however I would disagree that the slider itself if necessarily site design, I would put it as a cross between content and design.  Its something that I personally would use divs for but see nothing wrong with using imgs for.